# how find regular expression of permalink structure?

Tags: regex

I want to redirect many addresses from 404 to 410.but I need find out a regular expression of a permalink structure to use in plugin option. The permalink structure is: `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` What is a regular expression of this permalink structure?!

Comment: /(\d*)/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*) is right?!

Comment: Please provide an actual sample input (not placeholders like `%year%`) and desired output for the input.

Comment: http://akhbartop.com/1395/08/27/ارزش-تغذیه-ای-نخود-فرنگی/
this is a sample of old url

Comment: `\/([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/` will match 3 groups(1395,08,27).